# C++ user input closes program debug

Tags: c++, debugging, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

I got a C++ program that waits for user input and only closes if the user inputs 'q', and will loop back to the menu if anything else is entered.

At least that's what it's supposed to do.  Instead of looping back, the program closes anyway.

```
int main()
{   
    Hierarchy roster;
    char input=' ';
    bool done = false;
    string first, last, full, boss, title;
    while (done != true){
    cout << "Organizational Chart builder, version 0.1" << endl;
    cout << "Please choose your next command: /n";
    cout << "    q   to quit the program " << endl;
    cout << "    a   to add a person " << endl;
    cout << "    c   to count the number of people under someone" << endl;
    cout << "    p   to print the hierarchy " << endl;
    cout << "    r   to remove someone from the hierarchy " << endl;

    cin >> input;

    switch(input)
    {
    case 'q':
        done = true;
        break;
    case 'a':

        cout << "Please enter the person't first name:  ";
        cin >> first;
        cout << "Please enter the person's last name:  ";
        cin >> last;
        cout << "Please enter the person's title";
        cin >> title;
        cout << "Please enter " + first + last +"'s boss. Please enter the full name and title.  If there is none, type none:";
        cin >> boss;
        if (boss == "none")
        roster.insert(full);
        else 
        roster.contains(boss);
        roster.insert(full);
        break;

    case'c':

        cout << "Enter the first name of the person you are searching for:   ";
        cin >> first;
        cout << "Enter the last name:  ";
        cin >> last;
        cout << "What is the person's title:";
        cin >> title;
        full = first + " " + last + " " + title;
        roster.contains(full);
        roster.countb(full);
        break;

    case 'p':
        roster.print();
        break;

    case 'r':

        cout << "Please enter the first, last, and title of the person you want removed:  ";
        cin >> full;
        roster.removeNode(full);
        break;

    }
  }
cout << "Program closed.  " << endl;
return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: Got it working now.  Thanks

Comment: You should indent your code better, that helps a lot in cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement is in your while loop. Take it out and you should be okay.

ie. `return 0;}}` -> `} return 0;}`